# Leg-press for women

Tags: gym, strength-training

Is it true that taking too much of weight on the leg-press machine can affect a woman's body.If so what could be an alternative to the same ?

Comment: What do you mean by "affect"?

Comment: @heenasurve The question is very vague which Dave noted. Please provide more details so that the community has a better understanding of what it is you want answered. You'll also get a better that way too.

Comment: The reason i asked this question is because there are certain exercises that are believed to have alternatives especially when it comes to women.Is it completely safe to be doing this exercise?

Comment: No exercise is "completely safe". Nothing is. I would recommend doing back squat over leg-press though as I have seen a lot more people acutely injure themselves on it over back squatting.

Answer (score 1):

By "affect" do you mean make you look like a male bodybuilder? if yes, then the answer is "surely no". There is a misconception about women and weight lifting, a lot of women think that if they do some weight training they will grow huge muscles like male bodybuilders.

While increasing weight will make you build a bit more muscles of course, but there is a big difference in the physiology of men vs women, of which : Men have more muscles, have more testosterone (which helps build muscles),etc..

My personal recommendation if you want to "tone" your body, all you need to do is "body-weight" training. It will make you build the necessary nice looking muscles, strength, endurance, and will give you a much better looking shape than machines and body building. body weight training might not be suitable for someone joining a body building competition, but it is the BEST for someone who want to tone their body and have good shape. (I assume that's what you are aiming at)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the leg press will affect your body. It will help make you stronger, and look more fit. A barbell squat is often advocated as a better alternative to the leg press machine. It activates more muscles during the exercise, specifically your core (back and abs).

Answer (score -1):

According my thinking as half of our body's mass consists of quadriceps, thighs, calves, and buttocks, so leg press will definitely affect your body. Not only it will make you fit but also stronger.

If you are thinking that after using the leg press machine and doing heavy weight lifting you will develop muscles like a bulky men body builder the answer is a big NO!.

If you don't want to go for a leg press, you should try Squats. But i would recommend you to go for a leg press machine. You can read more about leg press machine using [this article](https://menslift.com/best-leg-press-machines/) where they have mentioned why working on leg press machine is essential for both men & women and have also outlined some of the best leg press machines including their pros and cons, features, specifications etc,.